# Restarting Apache kill background process

Tags: php, apache, background-process

I have a script `startbg.php`:

```
echo `/usr/bin/php $dir/runbg.php >> $dir/logbg.txt 2>&1 &`;
```

Which I call from the web (via HTTP/Apache).

It runs `runbg.php` in a background process.

But if I restart Apache (`/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`), the background process is killed.

Is there anyway I can keep the process running in the background?

Comment: Have you tried running it from [command line](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php)?

Comment: @RenePot I need to restart Apache to make configuration changes.

Comment: The script runs fine from the command line. It also runs fine from `exec` in PHP. The problem is that it stops when Apache is restarted if it was executed from a requested page.

Comment: the problem is that when pstree, the background process isn't listed as a child of apache2 ..., I am having troubles to find evidence of the relation between these 2 processes

Answer (score 1):

You could open up an instance of [PHP's internal webserver](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) (As of PHP 5.4.0, the CLI SAPI provides a built-in web server.) in my test killing `httpd.exe` did not effect `php.exe:8000`

```
<?php 
//Tested with windows

chdir('../php');
//S = Server, listen interface 0.0.0.0 = all : port 8000
//t = Served document root
echo `php -S 0.0.0.0:8000 -t C:\\xampp\\htdocs >> C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\logbg.txt 2>&1 &`;
?>
```

So possibly (untested):

```
echo `/usr/bin/php -S 0.0.0.0:8000 -t /srv/www/yoursite.com/public_html >> /srv/www/yoursite.com/public_html/logbg.txt 2>&1 &$dir/runbg.php >> $dir/logbg.txt 2>&1 &`;
```

Tho id have no idea how to kill it :s

Comment: Seems hacky. And I'm running PHP 5.3, nice try though :)

Comment: IMHO using php -S which is for develpment purpose for such a thing is not remmanded. A real politic of administration of the Apache should be taken to avoid to kill the process that are still running. On a production environment I manage I cant restart anything until everything is finished. Ortherwise we warn the users and plan to do a maintenance. My 2 coins ;)

Comment: @FoxMaSk yeah i agree. id be interested to know if the OPS question is possible to still use apache after killing it.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone what do you mean still use Apache after killing it?

Answer (score 0):

You should change process group id of `startbg.php` or `runbg.php`.

Apache/PHP sends signals to all children of its process group.
I cannot find any document on the feature.
However, I resolved the issue with calling `setpgid()` from spawned 
process.

Answer (score 0):

One way to allow the process to continue running without apache is to make it a service. Then activate the service (service runbg start) with your command. If you don't make the service normally running, then it will depend on your command to start after a reboot, but will not die with apache restarting.